# Bugs when viewing comments as a logged-out user in mobile view

Tags: bug, comments, design, mobile-web, anonymous

A few bugs happens when viewing comments by using the mobile view of Stack Exchange sites, as an anonymous user.

### Bug #1

The first is about the "add a comment" link missing. When not logged-in, if a post has no comments, **the "add a comment" link** is missing.

[image]

It displays again when navigating to the top of the page, logging in into one's SE account and navigating again to the post.

### Bug #2

The second is about the "add a comment" link. It actually displays to anonymous users if the post has been commented on. The link is clickable, but nothing happens when clicking on it in mobile view; it just adds `#tap-top` to the address bar's URL.

[image]

There is no visual feedback to the user, such as redirecting to the login page, or displaying a tooltip as follows:

[image]

### Proposed solution

The bug #1 may be solved by including the "add a comment" at the bottom of every post (question or answer), whether it has been commented on or not.

I think the bug #2 may be solved by either:

- redirecting to the login page on click
- displaying a tooltip which invites the anonymous user to log in. This is the preferred solution because it is consistent with the vote button behavior.

---

Although the screenshots were taken on Stack Overflow, this seems to happen on every Stack Exchange site.

Comment: _"displaying a tooltip which invites the anonymous user to log in."_ that is actually what is done on the main site so just appears to be a lack of functionality for the mobile one.

Comment: This is not exactly a tooltip, but a pop-up on the main site. Nevertheless, it is always frustrating for mobile users to except an action when clicking a link, and seeing nothing happened.